# Undecidable problems with efficient heuristics

Tags: computability

Are there some undecidable problems for which there are efficient heuristic algorithms, that succeed on a sufficiently large subset of inputs to be worth using?

The one application that comes to mind is program static analysis: clearly undecidable (assuming infinite memory – I believe that it is PSPACE-complete if memory is finite but no practical algorithm I know of makes use of this, other than to bound the values of pointers), but in some cases it is possible to prove that a program satisfies a certain property.

Comment: It sounds like you've answered your own question: yes, there are such problems, and you've given one example.  What more are you looking for?  It sounds like you're calling for a list of examples.  We don't have a strict policy for list questions, but there is a 
[general dislike](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/).  Also, there's no way anyone can compile a comprehensive list of all such examples, so I'm not seeing how this question is answerable in its current form.

Comment: Termination and null pointer checking are two problems that even if undecidable seem to have been subject to lots of attention and heuristics in the literature

Comment: @DW I would like to know information about the general class of problems: Why do some undecidable problems have good heuristics, and others do not?